# Ndb Doesn't Recognize Model Type Properly (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am having a huge and confusing issue. I have a model, that most definitely has certain properties, let's call them, name and text, but for some reason when I try to instantiate an instance of that model, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'FakeModel' has no attribute 'text'
```

The model class looks something like this:

```
class FakeModel(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    text = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

and I'm calling it in a route/endpoint like this:

```
model = FakeModel(
    id=id_that_is_calculated_in_code,
    name=name, #variable 'name' got from request
    text=text #variable 'text' got from request
)
```

Strange things:
- This worked plenty of times before, I have no idea what is causing this to break now.
- When I remove the 'text' specification from the constructor, I get another error telling me that i need to put that there because it's required. This means it definitely is looking at the right model class.

```
BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: text
```

- Sometimes if I switch the line order of the properties, I instead get an error telling me that 'name' is not a property.

EDIT: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I found that this error disappears when I remove the import of a different model class from a different file. This undefined behavior is replaced with other seemingly random failures elsewhere in the code.

I have a polymodel class from which other classes inherit; some models store a KeyProperty to that parent class, and store keys of it's children i.e.

```
class Parent(polymodel.PolyModel):
    def method1(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def method1(self):
    """
     some logic happens here which does not happen
     in the parent's method, which is meant to be overloaded
    """

class OtherEntity(ndb.Model):
    enkey = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Parent)
```

At seemingly random times (not every time), when I have an OtherEntity instance and call
`instance.enkey.get().method1()`

I get a failure or `None` return because the code is treating the entity pulled by the key as a Parent object, not a Child, and so calling Parent's version of method1() which is just pass. This has been verified with logging.

It's very strange to me because the class I imported was not related to this "FakeModel" class at all, and neither was the file it was imported from. Overall, It appears that i'm seeing some type of undefined behavior; something I have never seen before with python, or with google app engine. I suppose I'm now wondering if 'undefined behavior' as in that which can occur in C/C++ can happen in python/GAE, and if so what it's sources are.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I feel totally crazy, and I have no idea what is going on. Please help.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without a reproducible example, but it looks like you could be redefining FakeModel somewhere.  I'd suggest searching your source for `FakeModel =` to see if that finds anything suspicious.

Comment: Please show the full context of that first error. Note that it says the *type* object has no attribute "text" - which implies that somewhere you are doing `FakeModel.text` rather than `my_fake_model_instance.text`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's a very large code base for my company; it would be hard to show the full context without revealing sensitive architectural details. I think it says the model name instead of the instance because that model's constructor is being called, as in the second code snippet.

Comment: No, that would *not* give that error. As I said, the giveaway is that it mentions a "type object", which means you are referring to FakeModel.text somewhere. But we can't help you without at least seeing the traceback.

Comment: For ndb, if you call the constructor of a class that extends ndb.Model with a property that you have not defined as an ndb property within its class definition, it will throw that error. I've seen it happen before for typos. There have been some developments that I will include in an edit.